# Custard - How much milk can one egg set?

Tags: custard

If I had one whole egg (my understanding being that the white has more 'setting power' than the yolk), how much milk would I be able to set?

If I tried to set 2 cups of milk with 1 egg, can I expect something like a creme anglaise or something thicker?

Comment: I've found that **three** normal-size eggs and precisely **one cup** of **full** cream, works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on how thick you want it.  Some sites recommend [one egg or 2 yolks per cup of milk](http://www.incredibleegg.org/egg-facts/eggcyclopedia/c/custard).  Ruhlman mentions [2 eggs per cup as 'standard', with 1 egg able to thicken 3/4 of a cup of liquid (but more fat helps)](http://ruhlman.com/2009/01/blogging-elements-of-cooking-custard/).

I can't comment on thickness of creme anglaise -- I had to gave up dairy years ago, and that's not something that I've ever made.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding (from school days, Mrs Crabtree would be surprised) is that 1 medium egg will set 1/4 pint UK.  That's 5 fl oz UK.  USA is different and metric different again.

I use 1 FRESH medium egg to set 150mls of milk.

Comment: My compliments to Mrs Crabtree and welcome to Seasoned Advice to you! Don't forget to take the [tour] and browse our [help] to,learn more about this site.

Comment: fl oz are the same between US and UK (although pints are different ... a US pint is 1 pound of water (16 fl oz) instead of the UK 20 fl oz)

Answer (score 1):

Just checking this out for a class I am teaching and confirmed with a quick look at 'Cooking Explained' Barbara Hammond, Longmans 1966, and yes, she says 2 meium eggs to half a pint (UK measures), 4 to 5 pz shortcrust pastry and a 7 ins sandwich tin to bake it in.

If its a pouring custard (creme anglaise ) 1 egg o half a pint creamy milk or light cream.